# In Android How to remove Localization Details (English(United States)) from our service name

Tags: android

I have developed a soft keyboard app. which works fine . but after installation when user opens list of keybords for selection then service name shows like English(United States) #BenificaMoji whereas service name should be show like only #BenficaMoji . so how can i remove English(United States) from our service name.and show service name like #PepsiMoji ,show in following image link.
[Click here for image to understand problem exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRh6u.png)

here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.crafts">

 <uses-permission     
    android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission  
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission      
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category  
             android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".keybord.SoftKeyboard"
        android:description="@string/app_name"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod"
                android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.view.im"
            android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.crafts.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>

    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
 </application>
```

String.xml is---

```
<resources>
   <string name="app_name">#BenficaMoji</string>

   <string name="ime_name">Easy Moji Keyboard</string>

   <!-- Symbols that are commonly considered word separators in this    
         language -->
   <string name="word_separators">\u0020.,;:!?\n()             
                     []*&amp;@{}/&lt;&gt;_+=|&quot;</string>

   <!-- Labels on soft keys -->
   <string name="label_go_key">Go</string>
   <string name="label_next_key">Next</string>
   <string name="label_send_key">Send</string>
   <string name="label_done_key">Done</string>
   <string name="label_enter_key">Enter</string>
   <string name="label_search_key">Enter</string>
   </resources>
```

Comment: Please show the AndroidManifest.xml file for your keyboard app as well as any values from strings.xml which are used in it.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xm

Comment: hi Code-Apprentice , please review my AndroidManifeast.xml and string.xml

Answer (score 1):

i resolved  this issue . to remove localization we have to remove subtype ....> tag in our method.xml, in which i specified android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US".